# Azure Function : no logging after upgrading to .NET 8

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-isolated

I have upgraded my Azure functions to .NET 8. Since upgrading I no longer see any of my `_logger.LogInformation` events. Only errors get logged

I have reviewed this document (How to configure monitoring for Azure Functions) and adjusted my host.json accordingly.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2

[image]

This is my `host.json` file

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Function.IngressWebContent": "Information",
      "Function.IngressWebContent.User": "Information",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "Information",
      "Function": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

These are the relevant parts of my code:

```
public class IngressWebContentFunction
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

    public IngressWebContentFunction(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<IngressWebContentFunction>();
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }

[Function("IngressWebContent")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestData req, string hostname)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("I cannot see the message in the portal");
    // ...
}
```

I have tried different logging levels but that makes no difference

```
_logger.LogTrace("LogTrace");
_logger.LogDebug("LogDebug");
```

When I run the functions locally, I do see my events

Comment: I've had problems with Azure WebJob when upgraded to .NET 8 but they disappeared when I downgraded to .NET 7. Can you downgrade as well and see if your logs work again?

Comment: It is not really an option. It is a large project and I some of the nuget packages are using v 8. I have to roll forward

Comment: I just tried to create a new function app and create a new function project using vs code and deployed a standard http trigger function. Same issue. Nothing is being logged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the issue resolved by replacing my Program.cs with this. [1]

A code comment in the file says: The Application Insights SDK adds a default logging filter that instructs ILogger to capture only Warning and more severe logs. Application Insights requires an explicit override.

[1] https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/blob/main/samples/FunctionApp/Program.cs

Comment: I have copied your solution, but still get no "trace" or "debug" level logs in AppInsights. Information, Warning and Error /Exception show up fine. Did you ever get this working with trace and debug?

Comment: I referred to above link and added LoggerFilterOptions for .Net 8.0. It started working for me as well.

Comment: I am confused by this statement from MS: "The Functions host and the isolated process worker have separate configuration for log levels, etc. Any Application Insights configuration in host.json will not affect the logging from the worker, and similarly, configuration made in your worker code will not impact logging from the host. You need to apply changes in both places if your scenario requires customization at both layers." Does it mean, I still need to modify the default host.json file and add LogLevel configuraiton there as well?

Answer (score 2):

This is my very basic `host.json` that works for my azure functions. Take it from here and try to adapt it by adding slowly your configuration and see where it stops working.

```
{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
        "samplingSettings": {
            "isEnabled": true,
            "excludedTypes": "Request"
        },
        "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for .NET 8 and Azure Functions v4.