# Azure Isolated Function logs all App Insights logs as "Trace" and "Information" severity

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have a .NET 8 Isolated function using v4.
I am following this guide here to get AppInsights working and using the latest AppInsights from Nuget.
My Program.cs looks nearly identical their example they give here: https://github.com/devops-circle/Azure-Functions-Logging-Tests/blob/master/Func.Isolated.Net7.With.AI/Program.cs

In my function, I do something simple like this to test logging:

```
        _logger.LogTrace("TestLog Trace");
        _logger.LogInformation("TestLog Information");
        _logger.LogError( "TestLog Error");
        _logger.LogError(new Exception("something wrong"),"TestLog ErrorWithException");
```

The logs show up in the Transaction search in Application insights, but they all show up as Trace entries, and the Severity level is always "Information"

[image]

Here is my apsettings.json:

```
    {
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    SNIPPED
  },
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Trace",
      "xxFunction.DoSomeAction": "Debug",
      "xxFunction.Login": "Debug",
      "xxFunction.WelcomeGiftQueue": "Debug"
    },
    "extensions": {
      "queues": {
        "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:10",
        "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
        "batchSize": 16,
        "maxDequeueCount": 5,
        "newBatchThreshold": 8,
        "messageEncoding": "base64"
      }
    }
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my Program.cs:

```
using Application.Interfaces;
using AzureFunctionApp.Functions.Middleware;
using Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Azure.Core.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public class Program
{
    static ILogger _logger;

    public Program(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(builder =>
            {
                builder.UseMiddleware<ExceptionLoggingMiddleware>();

                builder.UseWhen<AuthenticationMiddleware>(ctx =>
                {
                    return ctx.FunctionDefinition.InputBindings.Values
                                  .First(a => a.Type.EndsWith("Trigger")).Type == "httpTrigger";
                });
            })
            .ConfigureServices((ctx, serviceProvider) =>
            {
                serviceProvider.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();

                serviceProvider.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();

                serviceProvider.Configure<WorkerOptions>(workerOptions =>
                {
                    JsonSerializerSettings settings = NewtonsoftJsonObjectSerializer.CreateJsonSerializerSettings();
                    settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                    settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                    workerOptions.Serializer = new NewtonsoftJsonObjectSerializer(settings);
                });

                serviceProvider.AddInfrastructureServices(ctx.Configuration);
            })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddSimpleConsole(console =>
                {
                    console.IncludeScopes = true;
                });

                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            })
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The guide you are following is for `.NET 7 isolated`.

I created a sample `.NET 8 isolated` Http Trigger function
and added your logging sample.

I added `loglevel` in my `host.json`:

```json
    "logging": {
        "logLevel": {
            "default": "Trace"
        },
```

and its showing correct `logs` and `severity Level` correct.

**`host.json`:**

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "logLevel": {
            "default": "Trace"
        },
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
                
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

**`program.cs`:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**`HttpTrigger.cs`:**

```cs
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public class HttpTrigger1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public HttpTrigger1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<HttpTrigger1>();
        }

        [Function("HttpTrigger1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("Tracelog warning");
            _logger.LogError( "Tracelog Error");

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**`*.cproj`:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

[image]

[image]

### **Edit** -------

I am able to get the `LogTrace` and `LogDebug` value by adding part of your code in my `program.cs` with some changes, instead of using `logging.AddSimpleConsole` I used `logging.AddApplicationInsights` and removed `logging.ClearProviders();`.

```
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: true);
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddApplicationInsights(console =>
                {
                    console.IncludeScopes = true;
                });

                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            })
            .Build();
```

##**My full code:**

**`host.json`:**

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "logLevel": {
            "default": "Trace"
        },
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
                
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

**`program.cs`:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
        services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            LoggerFilterRule toRemove = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");

            if (toRemove is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(toRemove);
            }
        });
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
    {
        config.AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: true);
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddApplicationInsights(console =>
                {
                    console.IncludeScopes = true;
                });

                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**`HttpTrigger.cs`:**

```cs
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogTrace("Testlog Trace");
            _logger.LogDebug("Testlog Debug");
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            _logger.LogWarning("Testlog Warning");
            _logger.LogError("TestLog Error");
            _logger.LogError(new Exception("something wrong"), "TestLog ErrorWithException");


            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

[image]

Comment: hi Vivek, thank you so much for taking the time to test this. If I use your solution, it partially fixes my issue. Exceptions, Warning, and Error is all being logged correctly now, but for some reason, my debug and trace logs are completely missing from the logs. If I add back in my previous solution, I was getting all the traces and debug statements, but everything was written as "Information". For some reason, my host.json won't let debug/trace get logged and my appsettings.json logs everything but puts the wrong category. Are you able to get debug and trace logs working?

Comment: I am also facing this issue for `Information` and `Trace` and `Debug` for `.NET 8`.
I am able to get the `Information` adding `s.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>` section from the GitHub [documnet](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/blob/main/samples/FunctionApp/Program.cs), [Image](https://i.imgur.com/FJu5Uth.png)

Comment: You can check this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77690726/azure-function-no-logging-after-upgrading-to-net-8) too.

Comment: @vivkek thanks, but I have copied the exact solution, and I see "Information" logs, but still no "Trace" or "Debug" logs show up at all in AppInsights. I am now using the exact Program.CS and host.json provided in this post and the link you shared

Comment: I think I have it working in a hacky way by manually setting the minimum log level in ConfigureLogging. Still would like it to just use the config value though. See this one https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8901

Comment: @user3010678 I have updated my answer with new code which worked for trace and debug log. I hope it helps you.