# Azure Function logging to App Insights won't log below warning level

Tags: c#, logging, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, .net-8.0

I have created a new Azure Function app with several functions in it, but I cannot for the life of me get it to print out Information logs.

I have some existing .NET 3.1 functions (created years ago) running on an older runtime (v3), and I have my hosts.json file set to this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "None",
      "Function.MyFunc.User": "Information",
      "Function.MyFunc": "Warning"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works PERFECTLY for my existing functions. It prints out errors thrown by the function and also logs the information I produce using `log.LogInformation(xxx)`.

The issue I'm having is that now I've created some new functions using .NET 8 and the newer runtime (v4), I just can't get them to log in the same way as my existing functions. For the record, I have scoured through every StackOverflow question I can find ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55408032/4662037)), and I've read through the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-log-levels) which details how to do it. Unfortunately, nothing I have tried works for me. Here is my new function, the host file, and the program file:

```
namespace XXX.Azure.FunctionApps.Mailbox.Functions
{
    public class GetMailFolders
    {
        private readonly ILogger<GetMailFolders> _logger;

        public GetMailFolders(ILogger<GetMailFolders> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger; // also tried loggerFactory version
        }

        [Function("GetMailFolders")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogTrace("Trace Msg");
            _logger.LogDebug("Debug Msg");
            _logger.LogInformation("Information Msg");
            _logger.LogWarning("Warning Msg");
            _logger.LogError("Error Msg");
            _logger.LogCritical("Critical Msg");

            return new OkObjectResult(null);
        }
    }
}
```

host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "Function.GetMailFolders": "Trace",
      "Function.GetMailFolders.User": "Trace"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

I have tried about 20 different combinations. Including the namespace of the function, `"Function.GetMailFolders"`, `"Function.GetMailFolders.User"`, `"default"`, `"Function"`, etc. Some settings have altered the verbosity of the function initialisation logs, and request logs, etc. But nothing I set will have any impact on the logs that I try to print in application insights, which is:

[image]

Even if I attempt to disable the logs completely, those three lines appear every time. No matter what I've tried, warning and above are the only ones that will ever show up.

Comment: What happens if you set a default log of information in the configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application insights captures only above `Warning` severity level by default. You need to disable it in part of service configuration.

For reference check this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#managing-log-levels).

For `Information` log, adding this part in `Program.cs` it worked:

```
.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.Services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            LoggerFilterRule defaultRule = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");
            if (defaultRule is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(defaultRule);
            }
        });
    })
```

**#My Code:**
**`Function1.cs`:**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            _logger.LogInformation("This is Information log");
            _logger.LogWarning("This is Warning log");
            _logger.LogError("This is Error log");
            _logger.LogCritical("This is Critical log");
            return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
        }
    }
}
```

**`Program.cs`:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.Services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            LoggerFilterRule defaultRule = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");
            if (defaultRule is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(defaultRule);
            }
        });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**`host.json`:**

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  }
}
```

## `OUTPUT`:

[image]

[image]

## Trace and below:

For Getting below `Information` severity level log add this in `Program.cs`, it works:

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
{
    config.AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: true);
})
.ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
{
    logging.AddApplicationInsights(console =>
    {
        console.IncludeScopes = true;
    });

    logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
})
```

**`Program.cs`:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.Services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            LoggerFilterRule defaultRule = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");
            if (defaultRule is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(defaultRule);
            }
        });
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
    {
        config.AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: true);
    })
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddApplicationInsights(console =>
        {
            console.IncludeScopes = true;
        });

        logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**`Function.cs`:**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            _logger.LogDebug("This is Debug log");
            _logger.LogTrace("This is Trace Log");
            _logger.LogInformation("This is Information log");
            _logger.LogWarning("This is Warning log");
            _logger.LogError("This is Error log");
            _logger.LogCritical("This is Critical log");
            return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
        }
    }
}
```

**`host.json`;**

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Trace"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  }
}
```

## `OUTPUT`:

[image]

[image]

For Reference check this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77827941/azure-isolated-function-logs-all-app-insights-logs-as-trace-and-information/77830565#77830565)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The change to the Program.cs file resolved the issue! Let me see if I can understand this then. So, the reason my existing functions work with the host.json file as is, is because they aren't isolated functions? Whilst isolated functions required extra some code in Program.cs?

Comment: @Murphybro2 Yes.

Comment: AFAIK .net 6 isolated works fine for information logs whithout any changes in program.cs

Comment: @NaveenSharma I'm well aware, thank you. At least give me a chance to test it and drink my morning coffee!

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya It does beg the question of how much impact the host.json file has now. I previously used it to suppress azure logs up to warning, and suppress my own up to information. With your help I can now get my information logs to show, but it feels like a game to replicate the previously functionality of suppressing all the MS logged guff that I don't need. For example, you showed how to include the host.json file in Program.cs, but it's clearly already being used as changing certain properties in the file affects the function. So why do we need to programmatically re-add it?

Comment: @Murphybro2 `host.json` file's default log level is `information` but Application insights captures `warning` and above. to get the information logs in Application insights.

Comment: But for trace and debug we need to include host.json file's logging as these logs are used rarely in Production environment

Comment: It is my conclusion As there is no MS document for explaination for adding additional line for `host.json` file  for `Trace` and `debug`.

Comment: I am confused by this statement from MS: "The Functions host and the isolated process worker have separate configuration for log levels, etc. Any Application Insights configuration in host.json will not affect the logging from the worker, and similarly, configuration made in your worker code will not impact logging from the host. You need to apply changes in both places if your scenario requires customization at both layers." Does it mean, I still need to modify the default host.json file and add LogLevel configuraiton there as well?

Comment: @OliverNilsen In `host.json` file by default  `loglevel` is set information. if you want different log level you need to  modify log level in host.json file.

Comment: The "loglevel" property is not to be found on a default .NET 8 Azure Function project when you create a new Azure Function project in Visual Studio.

Comment: @OliverNilsen Yes. In default function project no log level property is set or found, still default set level is information.